# How can i rotate a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

How can i rotate a uibarbuttonitem inside a uitoolbar? Because I rotated the uitoolbar (it's vertical now) and my bar button items are rotated too but i dont want that.

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115417/rotate-uibarbuttonitem?

Answer (score 1):

UIBarButtonItem does not extend UIView, so it cannot be transformed directly. You can add the UIBarButtonItem you wish to transform to a UIToolbar, transform the UIToolbar and then add the toolbar as a custom view to another UIBarButtonItem. This item can then be set as a navigation item or added to another UIToolbar.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemPlay target:self action:@selector(handleForwardItemTouch:)];

UIToolbar *backToolbar = [[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 44)] autorelease];
[backToolbar setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(-1, 1)];

UIBarButtonItem *backToolbarItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backToolbar] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backToolbarItem;
```

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12270718/419